# iPhone Application for Dynamic Bar Graph Creation

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios

I have an application in which I need to show some dynamic bar graphs (suppose data is of Sensex). Which libraries to add ? From where to start ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

core plot is your best bet for something like this. You can download some sample code and the library from the website below:

[Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/)

Comment: I got this "Core Plot" thing. But I don't know how to use it exactly ? Any help ?

Comment: check out the sample code on the core plot website. It should give you enough info to get started on your charts, including simple bar graphs.